# Creating DB in Mongo DB, Using Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I wrote the below code to create a database in Mongo DB,

```
client = MongoClient()
print (client.database_names())
db =client['test']
collection = db['test-collection']
dbNames = client.database_names()
print(dbNames)
```

[This](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/client/) document says, if the DB is already created it will able to access the collection in DB, and if DB is not available it will create a new DB and allow us to create collection.

I dont have any DB on my PC, and i am now running the above snippet to create the DB, but it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are created *as needed*. `client['test']` and `db['coll']` don't actually do anything, they merely give you an object that *if you were to use them to make any sort of query*, that query would be done on that database/collection. The act of getting that collection object in your Python code does not create any activity on the database server whatsoever.

The collection/database will be created when you first insert any data or create an index, or do anything else that would require actual data to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add new data to your collection. Database, and collection exists after the new document is created.

> ```
> from pymongo import MongoClient
> import datetime
>
> client = MongoClient()
> print (client.list_database_names())
> db =client['test']
> collection = db['test-collection']
>
> post = {"author": "Mike",
>          "text": "My first blog post!",
>          "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"],
>          "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
>
> post_id = collection.insert_one(post).inserted_id
>
> dbNames = client.list_database_names()
> print(dbNames)
> ```